# Media Queries with SCSS not applying

Tags: css, media-queries, sass

I'm trying to test the following code out in Chrome and Firefox and neither is picking it up. I have added it to the end of my stylesheet which works fine anyway.

```
@media all and (max-width : 850px) {
  h1#site-name {
    width: 100%;
    a {
      margin: auto;  
    }
  }

  nav#main-menu {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

I am re-sizing my browser window and the changes are obviously not taking effect at any width. The code is within a .scss file for reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: and you're absolutely sure you have properly compiled your scss to css?

Comment: I'm using Sasson the Drupal theme. Don't see why it couldn't handle that

Comment: `@` is problematic in SASS, because it's used for mixins. In certain versions this code will throw an error because it assumes a mixin declaration here. I noticed this problem on JSFiddle first. As far as I recall, this conflict has been fixed in a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mixins for media queries in scss too.

```
@mixin mq($mq) {
    @if $mq == medium {
        @media (max-width: 850px) { @content; }
    }
}

#main-menu {
    // default styles

    // media query 850px max-width
    @include mq(medium) {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Check out this article for more info.. http://css-tricks.com/media-queries-sass-3-2-and-codekit/